# How to map Employee's column - manager as Employee instance

Tags: java, sql, resultset

I should perform cursor moving in order to get all Employee instances.
Consider result set to be fully scrollable (back and forward, begin, end, etc.).
If an Employee has a Manager it should contain it as Employee instance as well.
This is a table Employee with some columns.

```
ID         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
FIRSTNAME  VARCHAR(10),
LASTNAME   VARCHAR(10),
MIDDLENAME VARCHAR(10),
POSITION   VARCHAR(9),
MANAGER    INTEGER,
HIREDATE   DATE,
SALARY     DOUBLE,
DEPARTMENT INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT FK_DEPTNO FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT (ID)
```

For exeample insert in table:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7654, 'JOHN', 'MARTIN', 'MARIA', 'SALESMAN', 7698, TO_DATE('28-9-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 1250, 30);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7698, 'JOHN', 'BLAKE', 'MARIA', 'MANAGER', 7839, TO_DATE('1-5-1981', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 2850, 30);
```

The manager `ID` first employee is `7698` and in instead of ID need to print all information about manаger. In final need to be

```
[Employee{id=7654, fullName=FullName{firstName=JOHN, lastName=MARTIN, middleName=MARIA}, position=SALESMAN, hired=1981-09-28, salary=1250.00000, manager=Employee{id=7698, fullName=FullName{firstName=JOHN, lastName=BLAKE, middleName=MARIA}, position=MANAGER, hired=1981-05-01, salary=2850.00000, manager=null}}
```

I create two maps and with `if` add employee to map `employ` and manager to map `manag`

```
 Map<Integer, Employee> manag = new HashMap<>();
            Map<Integer, Employee> employ = new HashMap<>();
        
        BigInteger id = BigInteger.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("id"));
                FullName fullname = new FullName(resultSet.getString("firstName"), resultSet.getString("lastName"), resultSet.getString("middleName"));
                Position position = Position.valueOf(resultSet.getString("position"));
                LocalDate hired = resultSet.getObject("hiredate", LocalDate.class);
                BigDecimal salary = BigDecimal.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("salary"));
                Employee manager = null;//String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("manager")) !=null? new Employee(id, fullname, position, hired, salary, null) : null;


if(resultSet.getString("position").equalsIgnoreCase("manager")) {
    Integer key = resultSet.getInt("id");
    Employee value = new Employee(id, fullname, position, hired, salary, null);
    manag.put(key, value);
} else {
    Integer key = resultSet.getInt("id");
    Employee value = new Employee(id, fullname, position, hired, salary, null);
    employ.put(key, value);
```

but what do I need to do next to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the MANAGER column is a foreign key on another employee, right?

If so, I would select all of the employee's without a manager first and add each one to a Map<Integer, Employee>. Then, when you iterate over the employee's with a manager, you can fetch the corresponding manager from this map and add it to the newly created employee instance.

This becomes more tricky if you have a hierarchy with more than 2 levels. If you can't order them by a property (e.g. department), then you have to read all of the employee's first and add their manager in a second step.

If you then need a set of employee's as a result, you'll only need to create a new Set of the maps' values.

Comment: I edited question, add some details, may be can help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).